# Is it possible to resize a p-column longtable?

Tags: tables

I have several tables, and I need to fit 2 tables in one page, but my tables are a slightly big to fit 2 in 1 page, can someone recommend me a solution?
 perhaps resize. Below is the code for one of my tables:

```
    \begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \caption{Мал бүртгэх use case-ийн тодорхойлолт.}
    \begin{longtable}{|l|p{10cm}|} 
        \hline
        Нэр: & Мал бүртгэх.  \\
        \hline
        ID: & 1 \\ 
        \hline
        Товч тайлбар: & Програмийг анх хэрэглэж эхлэхэд байгаа малаа \newline бүртгэх.\\
        \hline
        Үндсэн тоглогч: & Малчин. \\
        \hline
        Нэмэлт тоглогч: & Байхгүй. \\
        \hline
        Өмнөх нөхцөл: & 1. Хэрэглэгч Үндсэн цонхноос Малын бүртгэл цонх руу шилжсэн байх. \\ 
        \hline
        Үндсэн урсгал: & 1. Бүртгэх малын төрөлөө сонгосноор энэ use case эхэлнэ. \newline 
        2. Бүртгэх малын тоо толгой, төл малын тоо \newline талбаруудад өгөгдлүүд оруулна. \newline 
        3. Огноо сонгоно, сонгохгүй бол тухайн өдрийн \newline огноог автоматаар авна.\newline 
        4. Бүртгэх товч дарахад бүртгэл өгөгдлийн санд \newline нэмэгдэнэ.\newline
        5. Програмаас бүртгэл амжилттай болсон \newline тухай мэдээлэл өгнө. \\
        \hline
        Дараах нөхцөл: & 1. Мал бүртгэл нэмэгдсэн байна.\\
        \hline
        Альтернатив урсгал & 1. Тухайн төрлийн мал өмнө нь бүртгэгдсэн байвал давхардсан бүртгэл хийхгүй.\\
        \hline
    \end{longtable}
    \label{table:1}
\end{table}
```

I was using `tabular` instead of `longtable`, I thought longtables might solve my problem, but it seems to be the same as tabular, at least in my case.

Comment: `longtable` can not do anything if you put it inside a `table` as `table` makes an unbreakable box. If you want the table to break over the page use `longtable` if you want to make it smaller so it fits on a page, use `\small`  or `\footnotesize` or whatever size is needed

Comment: Would the tables be one above the other?

Comment: @Bernard, yes that's what I'm trying to do, I tried \resizebox to make the above table slightly smaller, but I'm getting "Too many }'s error", could it be that \resizebox doesn't work with this p-column table?

Comment: Using `\resizebox` is not recommended, as it can result in an unreadable table. Are the two tables of the same size (you only posted one)?

Comment: I have like 5-6 tables, all similar but different sizes, each one is taking like 55-60% of a page, so the rest is an empty space,  I'm trying to resize the tables slightly so that I can fit 2 tables per page, one above the other

Comment: Could you play both with `\arraystretch` and the fontsize. Down to `\footnotesize`, it remains readable.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3):

As others have already noted in the comments, *never* encase a `longtable` environment inside a `table` environment. On the other hand, if you do *not* want to allow page breaks inside the tabular material, *do not use* a `longtable` environment. The code and screenshot provided below illustrate both approaches. Observe that for the solution without page breaks, I suggest using a `tabularx` environment; this'll greatly simplify setting up the tables in a way that they all share the same width (likely: `\textwidth`). A separate suggestion: Do consider giving your tables a more "open" look by not using *any* vertical lines as well as fewer but well-spaced horizontal lines.

Finally, don't use any `\linebreak` or `\newline` instructions; they're not needed. Just use blank lines to indicate the equivalent of paragraph breaks.

[image]

```
% !TeX program = xelatex % or: lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[russian]{babel} % or bulgarian, or...??
\usepackage{longtable,array,booktabs,tabularx,ragged2e}
\usepackage[vmargin=1cm]{geometry}
\setlength\textwidth{12.2cm} % choose this parameter suitably
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}

% Choose a font that features Cyrillic glyphs
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}[Numbers=Lining]

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{longtable}{|l|p{8.4cm}|} 
\caption{Мал бүртгэх use case-ийн тодорхойлолт.}
\label{table1}\\
        \hline
        Нэр & Мал бүртгэх.  \\
        \hline
        ID & 1 \\ 
        \hline
        Товч тайлбар & Програмийг анх хэрэглэж эхлэхэд байгаа малаа бүртгэх.\\
        \hline
        Үндсэн тоглогч & Малчин. \\
        \hline
        Нэмэлт тоглогч & Байхгүй. \\
        \hline
        Өмнөх нөхцөл & 
        1. Хэрэглэгч Үндсэн цонхноос Малын бүртгэл цонх руу шилжсэн байх. \\ 
        \hline
        Үндсэн урсгал & % No more "\newline" directives!
        1. Бүртгэх малын төрөлөө сонгосноор энэ use case эхэлнэ. 

        2. Бүртгэх малын тоо толгой, төл малын тоо талбаруудад өгөгдлүүд оруулна. 

        3. Огноо сонгоно, сонгохгүй бол тухайн өдрийн   огноог автоматаар авна.

        4. Бүртгэх товч дарахад бүртгэл өгөгдлийн санд нэмэгдэнэ.

        5. Програмаас бүртгэл амжилттай болсон тухай мэдээлэл өгнө. \\
        \hline
        Дараах нөхцөл & 
        1. Мал бүртгэл нэмэгдсэн байна.\\
        \hline
        Альтернатив урсгал & 
        1. Тухайн төрлийн мал өмнө нь бүртгэгдсэн байвал давхардсан бүртгэл хийхгүй.\\
        \hline
\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Мал бүртгэх use case-ийн тодорхойлолт.}
\label{table2}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X@{}} 
\toprule
        Нэр & Мал бүртгэх.  \\
        \addlinespace
        ID & 1 \\ 
        \addlinespace
        Товч тайлбар & Програмийг анх хэрэглэж эхлэхэд 
            байгаа малаа бүртгэх.\\
        \addlinespace
        Үндсэн тоглогч & Малчин. \\
        \addlinespace
        Нэмэлт тоглогч & Байхгүй. \\
        \addlinespace
        Өмнөх нөхцөл & 
        1. Хэрэглэгч Үндсэн цонхноос Малын бүртгэл цонх руу шилжсэн байх. \\ 
        \addlinespace
        Үндсэн урсгал &
        1. Бүртгэх малын төрөлөө сонгосноор энэ use case эхэлнэ. 

        2. Бүртгэх малын тоо толгой, төл малын тоо талбаруудад өгөгдлүүд оруулна. 

        3. Огноо сонгоно, сонгохгүй бол тухайн өдрийн огноог автоматаар авна.

        4. Бүртгэх товч дарахад бүртгэл өгөгдлийн санд нэмэгдэнэ.

        5. Програмаас бүртгэл амжилттай болсон тухай мэдээлэл өгнө. \\
        \addlinespace
        Дараах нөхцөл & 
        1. Мал бүртгэл нэмэгдсэн байна.\\
        \addlinespace
        Альтернатив урсгал & 
        1. Тухайн төрлийн мал өмнө нь бүртгэгдсэн байвал давхардсан бүртгэл хийхгүй.\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but this is a standard I have to follow

Comment: @Taivna - It would be really helpful if you provided (a lot) more information about the "standard [you] have to follow". So far, you've been entirely silent about this presumably rather important aspect.

Comment: I gave up on trying to resizing my tables, instead I just used your example of longtable, thank you. I upvoted on your answer, but doesn't count since my reputation is below 15..